# Is the null character a whitespace in C?

Tags: c, scanf, whitespace

In the code below, `isspace` indicates that the null character is not a whitespace. Later in code the `fwrite` function writes a sequence of characters containing an intermediate and a final null character to a file.

The C17 standard indicates that the `s` conversion specifier "Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters." However, the `fscanf` at the end of the code only matches up to but not including the first null character.

Is there something in the standard that justifies this seemingly contradictory behavior? Are there bytes that are considered whitespace other than those indicated by `isspace`?  If so, what are they? I put a `\26` and a few other control characters in what I wrote to the file and `fscanf` read them just fine.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
   int x = isspace('\0');
   char inBuf[40];
   char outBuf[] = "Hello\0world\n";
   FILE *fp = fopen("MyFile.txt", "w+b");
   fwrite(outBuf, 1, sizeof(outBuf), fp);
   fflush(fp);
   rewind(fp);
   fscanf(fp, "%s", inBuf);
}
```

Comment: Downvotes signifiy insufficient research. In this case: it's simply well-defined what `isspace` considers space, and what not. And you could have looked that up yourself. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace

Comment: `fwrite()` works with binary data. 0s and 1s.

Comment: @AviBerger: Re “The convention is that '\0' (the null character) acts a sentinel and marks the end of the string”: That is irrelevant. The input of `fscanf` is a stream, not a string. The only mention of “string” in the C standard’s specification of `fscanf` is for the format string.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I'm well aware of what isspace considers to be whitespace, and that was part of the point I was trying to make.  isspace says the null character is not whitespace yet %s stops reading when it reaches it.  The standard indicates that %s stops reading when it gets to the first whitespace.  I can't find where it says anything about stopping when it reaches a null character, which is not a whitespace.

Comment: Re “Yet again I get an immediate downvote. Why?”: I did not vote, but your question contains a false premise (that `fscanf` did not read the null character), does not show how that premise was arrived at, and does not provide a program that would reproduce the issue (the program currently in the question does not produce any output that would demonstrate whether or not `fscanf` stopped at the null character).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I stand corrected. Thank you.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So do I. I mixed things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, the `fscanf` at the end of the code only matches up to but not including the first null character.

That is incorrect, as is demonstrated by the fact that the output of the following program is “"Hello", then "world".” `fscanf` reads the entire line up to the new-line character; it does not stop at the null character.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char inBuf[40] = {0};
    char outBuf[] = "Hello\0world\n";
    FILE *fp = fopen("MyFile.txt", "w+b");
    fwrite(outBuf, 1, sizeof(outBuf), fp);
    fflush(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%s", inBuf);
    printf("\"%s\", then \"%s\".\n", inBuf, inBuf + strlen(inBuf) + 1);
}
```

Comment: You are totally correct and thank you.  I made the mistake of merely hovering my mouse pointer over the inBuf variable rather than expanding it and looking at the total array.  Of course, just looking at it with a hover rather than expanding it only showed what the buffer contained up to the first null character :-(

Answer (score 2):

> the fscanf at the end of the code only matches up to but not including the first null character.

That is incorrect.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
   char sp[]  = "abc def\n";
   char nul[] = "abc\0def\n";

   char buf1[10];
   char buf2[10];

   printf( "%d\n", sscanf( sp,  "%s %s", buf1, buf2 ) );
   printf( "%d\n", sscanf( nul, "%s %s", buf1, buf2 ) );
}
```

```
2   // First `%s` stopped at space, leaving characters for second %s.
1   // First `%s` stopped at LF, leaving nothing for second %s.
```

As you can see, it read to the end of the string rather than stopping at the NUL.

(You could also use `ftell` after your `fscanf` to get the number of bytes read.)

You did not indicate how you came to the conclusion that `fscanf` stopped at the NUL, but I presume you used something like `printf( "%s\n", inBuf );`. *That* stops at the first NUL. Not the reading.